# laravel carbon original date changed after adding year

Tags: laravel, datetime, php-carbon

So I'm trying to add a year based on the user registration date, and I need to compare the date, but it's updating the original date from registration date.

```
$registered_at = Carbon::parse('2020-10-17 03:05:03');
$final_date = $registered_at->addYear();

echo $registered_at.'<br>';
echo $final_date;
```

result is the same, I want to preserved the `registered_at` date to 2020-10-17 03:05:03

```
registered_at : 2021-10-17 03:05:03
final date:     2021-10-17 03:05:03
```

I am expecting `2020-10-17 03:05:03`

```
registered_at : 2020-10-17 03:05:03
final date:     2021-10-17 03:05:03
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Carbon, when you call any method, it will change the instance.

In your case, you should use the `copy()` method to make a new instance before call method.

Ex:

```
$registered_at = Carbon::parse('2020-10-17 03:05:03');
$final_date = $registered_at->copy()->addYear();

echo $registered_at.'<br>';
echo $final_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `addYear()` value :

```
$registered_at = Carbon::parse('2020-10-17 03:05:03');
$final_date = $registered_at->addYear(1); // added 1 year

echo $registered_at; // 2020-10-17 03:05:03
echo $final_date; // 2021-10-17 03:05:03
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the instance first like this:

```
$date_parse    = Carbon::parse('2020-10-17 03:05:03');
$registered_at = $date_parse->copy();;
$final_date    = $date_parse->addYear();

echo $registered_at.'<br>';
echo $final_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't want your instances to be mutated on add/sub/set, use `CarbonImmutable`:

```
$registered_at = CarbonImmutable::parse('2020-10-17 03:05:03');
$final_date = $registered_at->addYear();

echo $registered_at.'<br>';
echo $final_date;
```

Else use `->copy()` to create a new instance.